# Issue with simple query

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I am having an issue with this simple query. I have to list all clients who didn't rent any movie from before 2015
Do I use Join for this or just a simple `WHERE` statement?

table clients:

```
customer_id,
name
```

table rentals:

```
customer_id, 
rental_date
```

Also, if my movie table contains description, title. How can I make a query to select both of them?

I can only do it like this

```
SELECT * from movies
WHERE description = 'something' && title ='something'
```

I know this && is wrong, but how can I also add the title to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a `not exists` condition:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   clients c
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   rentals r
                   WHERE  c.customer_id = r.customer_id AND
                          rental_date < DATE '2015-01-01'
```

Comment: Thanks, could you help me aswell with the second question in my post? Seems really simple, but I can't add && to it

Comment: @Stackerh the logical AND operator in SQL (and in PostgreSQL specifically) is the word `and`, not `&&`.